# missing login page when redirect

Tags: codeigniter

i was create codeigniter controller like this :

```
function Home() {
    parent::Controller();
    if(!$this->session->userdata('id')) 
        redirect ('login');
    $this->load->model('Home_Model');
}
```

but when i try to access the page, the redirect page now show. just show 404 not found but i was create login.php on controller and views also home_model.php on model.

what the problem with that code and how to fix that?

thank you

Comment: Can you show code of login controller please.??

Comment: also tell us which version of CI are you using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this line: `parent::Controller()`, I assume that you are using CodeIgniter 1. Since you are building pages like `home` and `login`, I assume that you are starting building a new website. If my assumptions are right, I suggest you using the latest CodeIgniter (v2.1.0 at the moment, *required PHP 5.1.6 or newer*). You can grab a copy at CodeIgniter Home Page.

First of all, I think you should check your error reporting level. It should be something like `error_reporting(E_ALL);` for debugging. If not yet, turn it on and run the code again. Maybe you will get your own answer after that :)

After that, you should try the code below for your constructor to check that your home controller process as you expected.

```
function Home()
{
    parent::Controller();
    echo 'Home Class Initialized';
}
```

1. It should at least show 404 page. If it doesn't print out anything then we need more information. Maybe you should turn on logging and analyze your log files: look for `/application/config/config.php`: `$config['log_threshold'] = 2;`
2. If it print out 'Home Class Initialized' follow by a 404 message: please check if your controller have something like:

   ```
   public function index()
   {
       echo 'Invoke default method';
   }
   ```

   If not yet, please add one. You may also want to take a look at using your own default method [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping)

   If it still a 404 then sorry, I have no idea. Maybe you should post more code.
3. If it print out 'Home Class Initialized' only: good. Now try this

   ```
   function Home()
   {
       parent::Controller();
       if ( ! $this->session->userdata('id'))
       {
           echo 'Redirecting to login page';
           //redirect ('login');
       }
       $this->load->model('Home_Model');
   }
   ```

   If this print out `Redirecting to login page`, it's now time for you to uncomment `//redirect ('login');` and  check the login page. Follow the same path with step 1 & 2.
   If not, check your session data: `var_dump($this->session->userdata('id')`. You could learn more about PHP falsehood [here](http://hyperpolyglot.org/scripting#falsehoods)
4. After all, if it still fails, consider using `__construct()` of PHP 5

   ```
   function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
       if ( ! $this->session->userdata('id'))
       {
           redirect ('login');
       }
       $this->load->model('Home_Model');
   }
   ```

*Other*: if you use this `$this->load->model('Home_Model');`, I think you will have to call home_model like this `$this->Home_Model->foo();` or there will be error access to NULL

Comment: the correct way is change redirect('login') with redirect('index.php/login) but error when i try to submit form on login page. my form like this <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('login/process_form'); ?>" process_form is function on controller/login.php